# Fluid layout to reorder container positions on small screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries, fluid-layout

I have a fluid layout with three containers say A[left sidebar], B [Main Container], C[right sidebar]. It works well in all screen sizes and arrange perfectly like one below the other A on top then B and last C (using media queries). But my requirement is to arrange like B, then A/C. I want my main container to come on top then sidebars.

I am sure this must be possible using CSS/Jquery and somebody would have done it but I'm getting its solution.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Here are two methods in CSS 1)http://dabblet.com/gist/7186549 2)http://dabblet.com/gist/7186624 in case you were still looking for a solution. I'm inclined towards the second method because the first can cause a few complexities. I can explain more about the methods if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do it, here is the answer if someone need it:

```
$('div.b').insertBefore($('div.a'));
```